# Parse postgres URL

Tags: java, postgresql, string-parsing

I'm trying to parse postgres db credentials, the format is as follows:

postgres://usernname:password@hostaddress:port/databasename

I'm  calling a method which returns these credentials in the form of a String in one line and trying to figure out if there is a simple way of parsing them out by username,password port etc instead of using regex.

Comment: Would you like to share the Java code you've tried so far?

Comment: Note: You generally shouldn't store passwords or any credentials within code. Therefore, "parsing" this string seems like a bad idea compared to having the credentials be injected into this URI from somewhere else (where your credentials would already be variables on their own)

Comment: By the way, I suggest learning about [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) interface for holding database credentials ([Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html)), the [`PGSimpleDataSource`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGSimpleDataSource.html) implementation, [directory service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service), and [Java Naming and Directory Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment by @OneCricketeer - you can use URI parser to do this kind of things and it seems also to me like a best possible solution. You can implement it this way:

```
try {
    URI uri = new URI("postgres://username:password@host.com:123/databasename");
    String[] userAndPassword = uri.getUserInfo().split(":");
    String user = userAndPassword[0];
    String password = userAndPassword[1];
    String host = uri.getHost();
    int port = uri.getPort();
    String database = uri.getPath().substring(1);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // handle invalid JDBC URL syntax
}
```

Also think about your JDBC URL - maybe you have some possibilities to keep those parameters separately in some config and create JDBC URL as a concatentation from these parameters? It would make things easier - this way you wouldn't need any extraction of the parameters from URL.

---

My old answer below (which is worse than usage of URI parser but I'm leaving it just for comparison with the above solution):

I would go with regex which would be not that hard in this case and it would be then easy to extract parts of data you need.

However, you can also use `split` method of String to get parts of the String you need, something like:

```
String url = "postgres://username:password@hostaddress:port/databasename";
String[] urlSplitByColon = url.split(":");
String[] passwordAndHost = urlSplitByColon[2].split("@");
String[] portAndDatabaseName = urlSplitByColon[3].split("/");

String username = urlSplitByColon[1].substring(2); // substring to cut out double slash at the beginning of username
String password = passwordAndHost[0];
String host = passwordAndHost[1];
String port = portAndDatabaseName[0];
String databaseName = portAndDatabaseName[1];
```

but I would really advice usage of regexp.

Comment: I suggest using an actual URI parser rather than split and substring or regex (URI's follow a defined spec)

Comment: I tried using the URI parser but didn't get it to work for some reason and then I noticed that I was storing credentials in a String, I changed that to String Array and then did .split(":") but since not all components of the String are NOT separated by colon(:), therefore had to apply regex to extract the values to suit my need.

Answer (score 0):

In Node JS, the code below is working for me to connect to Heroku Postgres:

```js
  // Using URL to parse database URL parameters
  const { URL } = require('url');
  const myURL =
  new URL(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
 
  // establishing a database connection
  var { Client } = require('pg');
  var client = new Client({
    user: myURL.username, //local: postgres
    host: myURL.hostname, //local: localhost
    database: myURL.pathname.substring(1), //local: postgres
    password: myURL.password, // local: admin
    port: myURL.port,
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  });
```

Had to use 'substring' to remove the '/' from the pathname in order to extract the database string.

Running Node v16.14.2

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.*;
import org.postgresql.Driver;
import org.postgresql.util.PGProperty;

public class ParsePostgreConnectionString {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

      // Sample PostgreSQL connection string
      String connectionString = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?user=myusername&password=mypassword";

      // Register the PostgreSQL JDBC driver
      DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());

      // Create a Properties object and set the connection properties
      Properties props = new Properties();
      PGProperty.parseConnectionString(connectionString, props);

      // Get the individual connection properties
      String host = props.getProperty("host");
      String port = props.getProperty("port");
      String databaseName = props.getProperty("databaseName");
      String user = props.getProperty("user");
      String password = props.getProperty("password");

      // Print out the parsed connection properties
      System.out.println("Host: " + host);
      System.out.println("Port: " + port);
      System.out.println("Database name: " + databaseName);
      System.out.println("User: " + user);
      System.out.println("Password: " + password);

      // Establish a connection to the database using the parsed connection properties
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, props);

      // Use the connection to interact with the database as needed
      // ...

      // Close the connection when finished
      conn.close();
   }
}
```